# how to paginate a recordset

Tags: jquery, mysql, json

I'm pulling a recordset from MySQL, encoding as json and sending it back to a DIV on another page.  I'm a little new to this data formatting so I'm wondering how do I go about using a pagination system?  Do I paginate the MySQL results OR do I do it with json using jquery?

Comment: You're supposed to paginate the results with `LIMIT`. Otherwise you're wasting a lot of resources.

Comment: I get that part, I just didn't know which was the best practice, formatting on the client side or server side.  Thanks for your response

Comment: Depends. Best practice for web apps is to only send JSON to the client, and have the client render it using templates. On the other hand, if you're a simple content site, with little javascript, sending HTML to the client is probably better, so javascript isn't required.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, I decided to send the request back to the server and return the proper JSON.  I'm not pulling a ton of data but I'm trying to keep an eye onto the future of this project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would paginate the data at the database tier. Depending on the size of the data you could end up with quite a bit of data on the client if you choose the other approach, which will affect performance.

Answer (score 0):

Most pagination systems are based on unordered lists (`ul`), others based on `table` element. Maybe you get some useful information, and plugins [here](http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-pagination-plugins/).